# Understanding more about IIS Threads and monitoring them

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis, threadpool

I understand that IIS uses a thread from Threadpool to serve an incoming Http Request and releases the thread once after it completes serving the request.

I want to play around this to understand, how many threads are possible in an IIS server for a specific hardware configuration and how many threads it can handle concurrently, and more related scenarios.

I'm looking for the way/tools that will help visually monitor the thread allocation/usage @ IIS.

I appreciate Any pointers/suggestions?

Comment: IIS not only uses multiple threads but also multiple processes, if you do learn the basics. So I wonder what exact you want to monitor. Windows provides performance counters to report threads inside a process if you check out MSDN and that can also be used to check threads in a single IIS worker process.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To see how many threads are possible in an IIS server for specific hardware, Click on the server. Then on the right side pane, double click on ASP like this.

[image]

[image]

The ASP Threads Per Processor Limit property specifies the maximum number of worker threads per processor that IIS creates. The default value of Threads Per Processor Limit is 25. The maximum recommended value for this property is 100.
To increase the value for the Threads Per Processor see [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee377050(v=bts.10).aspx).